# aiogram с webhook не завершат Task при ошибке

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiohttp

Есть телеграмм бот который стабильно работает на `polling`.

Решил переехать на `webhook` вроде все настроил, но ловлю такой баг.
Если возникает любое исключение, например:

> MessageNotModified

Бот просто зацикливается и пытается повторно выполнить `handler`, так же перестает отвечать на `CallbackQuery`.
Ощущение, что он не завершает задачу в цикле событий.

Можно отловить исключение - это само собой, но предполагаю, что могу быть редкие события которые создадут много проблем если вдруг зациклятся.

Сам бот:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
import logging
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from utils.filters import WorkOperatorFilter, OperatorFilter, AdminFilter
from data import config
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

storege = MemoryStorage()

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storege)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

dp.filters_factory.bind(
    OperatorFilter,
    exclude_event_handlers=[dp.channel_post_handlers, dp.edited_channel_post_handlers],
)

dp.filters_factory.bind(
    WorkOperatorFilter,
    exclude_event_handlers=[dp.channel_post_handlers, dp.edited_channel_post_handlers],

)

dp.filters_factory.bind(
    AdminFilter,
    exclude_event_handlers=[dp.channel_post_handlers, dp.edited_channel_post_handlers],
)




import logging

from data.config import WEBHOOK_PATH, WEBAPP_HOST, WEBAPP_PORT, WEBHOOK_URL
from utils.toolbox import reopen_start_state_chat_client
from create_bot import dp, bot
from aiogram import executor
from handlers import client, admin, operator
from utils.set_bot_commands import set_default_commands


async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)
    await set_default_commands(dp)
    await reopen_start_state_chat_client()

    print('Бот запущен')


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    logging.warning('Shutting down..')
    await bot.delete_webhook()
    await dp.storage.close()
    await dp.storage.wait_closed()
    logging.warning('Bye!')


admin.register_handlers_admins(dp)
operator.register_handlers_operators(dp)
client.register_handlers_client(dp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        skip_updates=True,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

Теоретический `handler`, в котором может произойти ошибка:

```
async def send_submenu_work_tickets_admin(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(callback.answer())
        data_sub_menu = tg.create_task(get_submenu_work_admin())
   
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
                                text=f'‍ Работа',
                                message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                                reply_markup=await in_kb_admin_submenu_work_tickets(data_sub_menu.result())
                                )
```

Ошибка с `webhook`:

```
ERROR:aiohttp.server:Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 433, in _handle_request
    resp = await request_handler(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 504, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py", line 954, in _iter
    resp = await method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/webhook.py", line 139, in post
    results = await self.process_update(update)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/webhook.py", line 190, in process_update
    return fut.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/Bot-tg/telegram_bot/handlers/admin.py", line 59, in send_submenu_work_tickets_admin
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 3096, in edit_message_text
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.EDIT_MESSAGE_TEXT, payload)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "/home/sunrise/support_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageNotModified: Message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным или может направить на ресурсы с информацией. Хочется видеть логику работы с ошибками, как при `polling`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать зацикливания и проблем с ответом на CallbackQuery при исключениях, вам может помочь указание обработчика исключений для диспетчера. Например, добавьте следующий код в свой код:

```
dp.on_exception(MessageNotModified, handler_function)
```

где `handler_function` - это функция, которая будет выполняться при возникновении исключения `MessageNotModified`. В этой функции вы можете обработать исключение и завершить задачу.

либо можно сделать, используя метод add_error_handler диспетчера.

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import StopHandler

async def on_error(dp, update, error):
    if isinstance(error, MessageNotModified):
        raise StopHandler()
    print(error)

dp.add_error_handler(on_error)
```

Comment: да, сейчас я и использую подобную конструкцию, что бы отлавливать ошибки и принудительно останавливать хендлеры. Однако, я считаю неадекватным то, что при поднятии любого исключения(даже ошибки в синтаксисе python) не завершают самостоятельно Task в основном event loop .
Мне кажется это большая проблема, необработанные исключения должны завершать task и я не понимаю где допустил ошибку при переходе на webhook, что создал такое.

Comment: можно контрибютить в библиотеку, чтобы предложить свой фиче-реквест на поведение таски

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это не дефолтное поведение и у всех ```ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-22' ....``` а не как у меня  ждет обработку ```ERROR:aiohttp.server:Error handling request...```?

Comment: вроде не дефолтное